# Hibernate mapping single class to multiple tables

Tags: java, database, hibernate

As iam very new to hibernate,

I wanted to capture borrowers details from a html form, this form roughly has 45 fields. These form data has to be stored in eight different tables. where we have scenario like one to many relation, one borrower will have multiple family members, family member details also submitted in the same form. keeping all this in mind i wanted to know which is the best way to do it in hibernate xml mapping.

Should i populate all 45 fields in single class and map it, or should i have separate class for each table and map it using `<joined-subclass>`  ...?

which is the best solution to do it, when end user fills all the form data and submits, data should be stored in all eight tables.

**Table structure** :

```
User_details, 
user_asset_details, 
user_income_details, 
user_family_members, 
user_family_details, 
user_misc_details
```

Comment: `this form roughly has 45 fields` you may not be able to change that and this is a little it off topic but this is way too many fields for a single form !

Comment: The best is to **not** use XML mappings, but annotations. You should have multiple entities associated with OneToOne, OneToMany and ManyToMany associations: One Borrower has Many FamilyMember. Inheritance is for is-a relationship: a Banana is-a Fruit.

Comment: actually i have 4 tabs, each tabs contains few fields, on click of next button user will be navigated to next tab. so finally when he submits in final tab it has to be stored.

Comment: but already our project uses xml mapping.... can i use annotations when rest of all uses xml. is there a way to migrate by keeping old mappings still in xml

Comment: If you already use XML, then use it everywhere, or replace it everywhere by annotations. The important point is to respect the associations between entities. Don't use inheritance where you shouldn't.

Comment: so now which is the best way to do it.... how would i go with it now, create separate entity class for each table and map it...?

Comment: @Santosh If I were new to Hibernate I would start persisting input from the form to **one single** entity. Then implement an appropriate mapping, and so on. Sort of the divide and conquer approach.

Comment: Basically, yes, you should have one entity per table, except when the table is a pure join table to contain an association (usually ManyToMany) between two tables.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get how you can have exact number of fields within *the entity* but also have one-to-many relation in the domain model? What happen when user would have 20 family members? :-)

You should define correct domain model, define correct relations including *parent* which contains field of list of *family members* etc.

This model should much more correspond to your DB schema including 8 tables.

Note that `join-table` is the pattern to express inheritance within DB modeling. It definitely  does not serve to divide one large class into more tables. Hibernate supports exactly opposite pattern named `component` which can allow you to store one-to-one relation within one database table.

As you talked about model in this way, maybe you would be interested in [domain driven design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design).